# Why checkbox needs timeout to be checked in Backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, coffeescript

```
@$el.html(@template())
@$('an_input').val('2')               # ---> this works
@$('selector').prop('checked', true) # ---> does not work  


@$el.html(@template())
@$('an_input').val('2')                  # ---> this works
setTimeout( ->
  @$('selector').prop('checked', true)  # ---> works!
  1000
)
```

Anyone knows why?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EC49U/

Comment: Probably because of the asynchronous nature of javascript. You need to add a callback after the successful loading of the template.

Comment: See that this would be weird, because I can set value to an input, isn't it?

Comment: True, it's a little odd, perhaps jquery processes val and prop differently with respect to the DOM. However I still think its an async issue. re-factor your code with the callback and see what happens.

Comment: I doubt this has anything to do with jQuery, can you confirm by using `$('selector')[0].checked = true`?

Comment: u can reduce that timeout to 0/1 and see if that works for u. so that u dont have to actually wait for 1 sec

Comment: You setTimeout has no timeout. The "1000" is part of the block

Comment: Reduced timeout to 1, worked

Comment: tried with [0].checked. going to do a fiddle.

Comment: I fixed also the timeout syntax with a named function and made the number the second argument in setTimeout, but anyway, iHave the same two scenarios.

Comment: How could a do a fiddle with JST?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/EC49U/

Answer (score 0):

It does work in a normal situation. It seems in your case, the selector cannot find the element you are targeting until after 1 second.
Here's a working sample with no timeout:
http://jsfiddle.net/gouegd/zXGVD/

Note I use checked="checked" instead of true which is more HTML-compliant I think.

```
$('#car').prop('checked', "checked")
```

Comment: jQuery converts `("checked", true)` to `checked="checked"`